# How to open different link in new tab with different popup buttons

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, popup

I'm using a button to open a ajax html popup and a link onclick at the same time.
But the problem is I have several buttons placed on the page and with each button I want to open different links any help appreciated

Heres the html code

```
<a href="test.html" class="ajax-popup-link">
    <button type="button" style="background:green;float:right;">
        Activate
     </button>
</a>
```

Heres the javascript function

```
<script src="../assets/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
       type: 'ajax',
       overflowY: 'scroll',
       closeOnContentClick: false
    });
    $('.ajax-popup-link').click(function(){
        window.open("/some-link.html");
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: can you give little bit more information ?

Comment: on click of different button i want to open different link instead of one

Comment: if you want that then @Jeff Clarke 's answer seems good

Answer (score 1):

I have got the workaround anyway 
here it is

```
<p onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_new')"><a class="ajax-popup-link" href="test.html" style="top:-10px;left:650px;background:green;text-align:center;height:50px;">ACTIVATE DEAL</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `click` function, just reference the `href` attribute instead of hard coding the link.  Also a good idea to prevent the browser's default behaviour on link click:

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open($(this).attr("href"));
});
```